# How to move the chart to the right side with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to create some charts. I added some gridlines in my charts and the result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RymNK.png). So I guess, I have to move the grid to the right side to identify with the axis y.I want also to fix the values in x axis (they have to be only 10 values for each line : 13000, 13100, 13200, 13300, 13400, 13500, 13600, 13700, 13800, 13900, 14000) Here is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


 <style> /* set the CSS */


.grid line {
  stroke: aquamarine;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke-width: 1;
}

</style>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #262f39;
}
</style>
<svg id="svg1" width="1000" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var svg1 = d3.select("#svg1"),
    margin = {top: 1, right: 0, bottom: 90, left: 50},
    width = 950 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g1 = svg1.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left   + "," + margin.top + ")");


var x = d3.scaleLinear()
.rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.rangeRound([height, 0]);

// gridlines in x axis function
function make_x_gridlines() {
    return d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(5)
}

// gridlines in y axis function
function make_y_gridlines() {
    return d3.axisLeft(y)
         .ticks(5)
 }

 var line = d3.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.frequency); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.output); });




 d3.csv("Measurements.csv", function(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  d.output = +d.output;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
   if (error) throw error;

 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; }));
 y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.output; }));

  g1.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("y", 11)
        .attr("dx", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Frequency");


  g1.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 15)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Mixer Output");

  g1.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "aquamarine")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 4)
      .attr("d", line);

      // add the X gridlines
  svg1.append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(make_x_gridlines()
          .tickSize(-height)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

  // add the Y gridlines
 svg1.append("g")
     .attr("class", "grid")
     .call(make_y_gridlines()
         .tickSize(-width)
         .tickFormat("")
     )


});

</script>
<svg id="svg2" width="1000" height="500"></svg>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var svg2 = d3.select("#svg2"),
    margin = {top: 1, right: 0, bottom: 90, left: 50},
    width = 950 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g2 = svg2.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left   + "," + margin.top + ")");


var x2 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y2 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    // gridlines in x axis function
    function make_x_gridlines() {
        return d3.axisBottom(x2)
            .ticks(10)
     }

    // gridlines in y axis function
function make_y_gridlines() {
    return d3.axisLeft(y2)
        .ticks(5)
}

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.frequency); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.output); });




d3.csv("m11.csv", function(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  d.output = +d.output;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; }));
 y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.output; }));

  g2.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
     .append("text")
     .attr("fill", "#000")
     .attr("y", 11)
     .attr("dx", "0.71em")
     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("Frequency");


 g2.append("g")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
     .append("text")
     .attr("fill", "#000")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
     .attr("y", 9)
     .attr("dy", "0.71em")
     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("Delay");

 g2.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "aquamarine")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", 4)
  .attr("d", line);

  // add the X gridlines
 svg2.append("g")
     .attr("class", "grid")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(make_x_gridlines()
       .tickSize(-height)
       .tickFormat("")
     )

     // add the Y gridlines
 svg2.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_gridlines()
      .tickSize(-width)
      .tickFormat("")
   )


});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle with the whole code?

Comment: Following [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) simple rules could improve your questions a lot. I suggest to follow them. I partially fixed your question now, but I can't be with you every time :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you used a g element to translate the graph and to add some margin, but you appended the grid directly to the svg.

Try to append the grid to the g element instead.